# How to send a GET request to ‘My XAMPP server’ using AJAX in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, google-chrome-extension

I'm finished a new REST API, I want to test it and send a GET request to ‘My XAMPP server url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php?a=ad"’ in my chrome extension using AJAX.

I tried many times, But failed... So how i can do it?

**Errors in the console:**

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php?a=ad'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**CODE**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php?a=ad',
        success:function(data){

        },
        error: function() {
            $('#notification-bar').text('An error occurred');
        }

    })
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Any errors in the console? The JS logic looks fine so you will need to debug the response

Comment: Well... done, I edited the question

Comment: In which case the problem is described in the error. You're making a non-secure request from a secure domain. You will need to run SSL on your local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the API URL to have `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP` should resolve this problem.

or

adding following code to the HTML page:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`